# Nginx location match causes 404

Tags: nginx

I am trying to add behavior for certain file types, but because my content isn't in the same folder, I hit a problem where the location match causes  Nginx to look for content in the wrong folder.

With the following, a request for `/wp-content/themes/ryu/fonts/ClearSans-Regular.woff` makes nginx look for the file at `/opt/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ryu/fonts/ClearSans-Regular.woff` whereas if I comment the `location ~* \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot`... part, Nginx looks for content in the right place.

Any clue how I can achieve this?

```
server {
  listen *:80;

  root /opt/wordpress;

  location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
  }

  location ~* \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires max;
  }

  location /wp-content/ {
    alias /opt/wp-content/;
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location / {
    alias /opt/public/;
    expires 1d;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri @wpsupercache;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't adding

```
root /opt/;
```

within the `ogg...` `location` stanza do what you want? That's assuming that the filesystem path for your example is `/opt/wp-content/themes/ryu/fonts/ClearSans-Regular.woff`

Comment: Or `alias /opt/wp-content/` more preferably.

Comment: right, but can't I have a location match that covers more than one root / alias?